# Select all frames at once in Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This could be a stupid questions for some. But its truly important for me.

I know how to switch frames using selenium webdriver.

However, is there a way to download all the page_source of the entire page for all the frames at once.
Instead of switching them again and again?

Could someone please let me know the command if it exists?

If not then please say there is none. And that should answer my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do it. Here is an answer I wrote once, that might help you to go through all iframes and retrieve whatever you want from each one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20891826/1382251.

Answer (score 0):

Webdrivers' getPageSource will return *some state in some formatting* of the last page the driver was on.

From the (java)docs, but most probably applies to other languages:

> getPageSource
>
> java.lang.String getPageSource()
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a
>   representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted
>   or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.
>   Think of it as an artist's impression.
>
> Returns:
>       The source of the current page

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29